# C#: Make System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery async by default

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, odata

Mono.Android requires me to do async queries. I can do that like this:

```
DataServiceQuery<T> dataServiceQuery = query as DataServiceQuery<T>;
return (new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<T>>()).FromAsync(dataServiceQuery.BeginExecute(null, null), asyncResult => dataServiceQuery.EndExecute(asyncResult)).Result;
```

The problem is that I don't want to call this method every time I'm querying because this forces my users that are using my library to call that method, otherwise Mono will crash, so I'd like to make DataServiceQuery do this by default. I can do this by overriding the GetEnumerator() function from DataServiceQuery, but it's constructor is private so I'm not allowed to do that. The only option I have left I guess is to recompile System.Data.Services.Client.dll with my changes. Maybe there is a trick with DataServiceContext but I'm honestly out of options.

Thanks for your help,
Maxim

Comment: Why not use callbacks in your methods? When the users of your library query your methods, they call `yourLib.ExecuteQuery(query, (result) => { ... });`, your method takes an `ExecuteQuery(string Query, Action<List<T>> Callback)`. But can't say for sure, need more info

Comment: The queries are LINQ queries on DataserviceQuery

Comment: Something like 'from item in lib.Items select item', and not 'lib.GetAsync(from item in lib.Items select item)'

Comment: Yes, that is fine. But what I mean is, Create your query as you wish. Inside your query where you have `TaskFactory`, rather create a new task, run your query and return a result when you have one `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { ... callback?.invoke(asyncResult)...});`

Comment: The code sample I gave should be run automatically when the user is querying

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this automatically, but you can make your statement nicer by making a new Select function called SelectAsync.

As a matter of fact this also fixes a problem with OData and LINQ because you had to wrap Selects in anonymous types, now you can call the Select after the query (which takes longer since you are querying the whole class, but this is not a problem to me).

Here is the code for the SelectAsync extension methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
{
    return queryable.SelectAsync(x => x);
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectAsync<T, TResult>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Function<T, TResult> selector)
{
    var dataServiceQuery = queryable as DataServiceQuery<T>;
    return Task.Run(async () => (await (new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<T>>()).FromAsync(dataServiceQuery.BeginExecute, dataServiceQuery. EndExecute, null)).Select(selector)).Result;
}
```

Executing a query with LINQ in Mono.Android is now more intuitive.

```
var itemNames = Items.Where(item => item.ID == 0).Select(item => item.Name);
var goodCars = Cars.Where(car => car.Fuel >= 0.5);
```

Translates to:

```
var itemNames = Items.Where(item => item.ID == 0).SelectAsync(item => item.Name);
var goodCars = Cars.Where(car => car.Fuel >= 0.5).SelectAsync();
```

As far as I know, this is as good as it can get because System.Data.Services is currently not fully supported in Mono.Android. This is a nice and intuitive workaround.

Sources:

- https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/